# Pagination on page 2+ only

Tags: pagination

So here is the code I have

```
<meta name="robots" content="follow, <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')==1)?'index':'noindex'?>" />
```

I am trying to have it set to only execute on pages 2 & above. Thus far I have tried

```
<meta name="robots" content="follow, <?php echo (get_query_var('paged')==2)?'index':'noindex'?>" />
```

But it's still executing on page 1?

Comment: What does the `<meta name="robots">` have to do with pagination?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to do this because you're trying to solve a problem you haven't mentioned, are you trying to prevent google indexing paginated pages?

Comment: @Tom J Nowell, this is correct, it's to have the paginated pages set to noindex, my homepage also list all the post so this is why I'm trying to skip page 1 and have pages 2+ set to "noindex, follow" because otherwise, the homepage of the site would inherently bet set to nofollow and deindexed since the homepage itself is paginated.

Comment: @kero The goal is to have the paginated pages (page 2 and up) set to "noindex, follow" and google states robots meta tag is the best way to ensure they don't index pages you don't want to be indexed.